# how can I convert an address into geographic coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, api, geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

guys

I am trying to write a code that converts an address to geographical co-ordinates.

Below is the code I am trying to use.

the Problem is that the code does not return any geographical co-ordinate, instead, it gives me the error

```
   File "C:\Users\user\.spyder-py3\untitled2.py", line 17, in <module>
    my_geo = results[0]['geometry']['location']

   IndexError: list index out of range
```

After looking around for the cause of the error, I discovered that the line:

```
results=geocode_site.json()['results']
```

returns an empty list.

When I try to run:

```
print(geocode_site.json)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
{'error_message': 'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. 
For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account', 'results': [], 
'status': 'REQUEST_DENIED'}
```

I am kind or new to all these. These errors are frustrating me.
can someone help me out?

I will be so grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: The essence of your problem is  **'REQUEST_DENIED.'**  'You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs..  Have you examined the contents of For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account'?

Answer (score 1):

Every Google Maps API request requires an API Key. And that API Key must belong to a project that must be associated to an open billing account. See here on [how to create a new project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#console) and here on [how to create a new Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#create_a_new_billing_account).

Although you did not put much details on how you are making a request, you appear to be using a 3rd party module to implement client side Geocoding. I would first advice that you take a look at its documentation to find where to add the required API Key in your code. If after your thorough research shows that this cannot be done, then its best to find something else.

The most recommended way is to instead make a server-side Geocoding web request. You can learn more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding).

But if you really need to make client-side Geocoding requests, then the next best thing is that you take a look at [Client Libraries for Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library). You can try following their guide for Python there, [Python Client for Google Maps Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python). But do note that even though that guide is on their official web site, they do not support this. As customers would not be able to restrict their API Keys that way and would leave those keys vulnerable for possible abuse and misuse if compromised. It is mentioned in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library#api-keys-and-client-ids) that:

- These libraries are not covered by the standard Google deprecation policy or support agreement.

To learn more on how to properly restrict an API Key, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices?hl=en